# MS Access Form with Values against Dates

Tags: forms

I want to create a form that could show money exchange rates plotted against dates for different currencies. Basically, I want to add these values in a simple form that has a date, a combo field to enter a currency name, and then a text box to enter the currency. Then I want to have another form which when I click should show a sort of summary form with money exchange rates plotted against dates. I can create a similar form with cross-tab queries but they can't update newer dates automatically when they are added.
Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table should be able to do it.You will have to add a home currency to the form, in the image attached, US Dollar is home country(this i have not made visible in the pivot, but you will see the exchange rates(arbitary data i have used) for dec 1st to 3rd 2021 for Canadian dollar, british pounds and australian dollar).

The pivot table automatically updates and allows for summary, and filtering by date.

play around with pivot table, you should be able to get what you want done.

The pivot table was placed on a form.
[image]